# Emit to socket with a particular object attribute

Tags: node.js, sockets, socket.io

I am adding the `username` to the socket object like this which is working fine

```
socket.on('add user', function (username) {
    socket.username = username;
});
```

Lets assume the `username` is `khawer` and now i want to emit to this socket where `username` is `khawer` but i am unable to do so.

I have tried this

```
io.sockets.connected[socket.username].emit('chat message', msg);
```

And this

```
io.sockets.sockets[socket.username].emit('chat message', msg);
```

But both did not work. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: I think you should use socket ID instead of username `io.sockets.connected[SomeSocketID].emit(...)`

Comment: Yes this works. As `socket.id` is an index of socket object then why `socket.username` is not the index?

Comment: `socket.username` is your own property.  The socket library doesn't do anything with it.  If you want an index by that property, you have to make your own index.

Comment: I think this is a disadvantage of socket.io. It has only socket.id for indexing

Comment: @Paramore - username is your own invention, not a property that socket.io has anything to do with.  If you want an index by something you invented, then you make your own index.  I've added several possible solutions to my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just assigning a `username` property to a socket does not make it so that it's indexed by name - thus you cannot do either of the types of lookups you're doing.

If you want to find a socket by username, you will either have to do a brute force search of all the sockets to find the one that has the same user name or you will have to create your own index of sockets by name.

---

If you want to do a brute force lookup to find it, you could do this:

```
var list = io.sockets.sockets;
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    if (list[i].username === "khawer") {
        list[i].emit('chat message', msg);
    }
}
```

---

You could also put each user into a chatroom with a name that matches their username.  Then, you could send to any given username by simply sending to the chatroom by that name.  You'd be using the chatroom feature as an index by username.  It would just require one extra step to put a socket into a chatroom that matches their username when they connect.

---

Or, each time a socket connects and disconnects, you could maintain your own socket index by username (this is relatively common).